# No module named 'pyspark' VSCODE Jupyter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Basically I installed pyspark and etc, he works in terminal and jupyterlab without problems, but in jupyter of vscode I have this error, why?

I set path, home variables of hadoop, spark and java, but in vscode not works and with others kernel I have the error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the package is not installed in the python environment that is VSCODE uses for Jupyter.

You need to verify where is the environment located and "`pip install the_package`" there.